# Capturing changes to MailItem.SendUsingAccount property in Outlook

Tags: events, outlook, vsto, mailitem

I am working on an Outlook extension that requires making a change to a MailItem open in a compose window if the SendUsingAccount property is changed via the GUI.  I would like to be albe to apply my changes automatically, but I cannot find any events that are raised when the user makes the change.  I have tried listening to the following events with no success:

- mailItem.PropertyChange
- mailItem.CustomAction
- mailItem.CustomPropertyChange

Are any events raised when the SendUsingAccount property changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, is the short answer.
You could hack up a timer to check for the change on the property.
Marcus

Comment: Thanks Marcus.  I setup a background thread with a timer to monitor it, but was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Maybe Subclassing is the way to go